# StreamCorruptedException wrong format

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, io

i have been trying to solve this problem and i read the other threads here on stackoverflow (and other websites), but couldn't find an answer.

Basically, i am developing an app that sends apk files through sockets. Before i start sending the file, i also send a string with the app name and the size of the correspondent apk file.

When i create the sockets (right at the beggining), i also send two messages, one from the client to the server, saying its nickname and one from the server to the client, just saying hello. These messages are sent fine.

The problem is when i try to read the appName and the fileSize.

EDIT : Just noticed that the character that shows up after the wrong format exception is not from the error. It changes depending on the app that i try to send.

Here is my code.

This is the run method of the inner class clientHandler (Runnable), where i create the stream objects on the client side.

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("ServerComm clientHandler - inside the thread run ..");
    try {
        this.in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());//criar os streams para cada um dos clientes
        this.out=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        try{
            System.out.println("SErverComm clientHandler - going to read the nickname.");
            String message = (String)this.in.readObject();
            String[] tmp=message.split(";:-");
            this.nickname=tmp[1];
            System.out.println("ServerComm clientHandler - the nickname of this person is : "+nickname);
            this.out.writeObject("Hello i am the server");
            System.out.println("serverComm clientHandler - just sent my message of hello from the server");
            handshakeDone=true;
            System.out.println("serverComm ClientHandler - the handshake is done ! ");
            connectedClients.put(nickname,this);
            ReceiveThread rec = new ReceiveThread(this);
            new Thread(rec){}.start();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then i start the receiving thread which is also a inner and RUnnable class code is :

```
private ClientHandler clientHandler;

public ReceiveThread(ClientHandler clientHandler) {
    this.clientHandler = clientHandler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = clientHandler.getIn();
        while(!serverSocket.isClosed()){
            try {
                System.out.println("Highway server comm receive thread - INSIDE THE WHILE CICLE, before the in.readObject");
                if(in==null){
                    System.out.println("serverComm - receiveThread the in object is null I am null");
                }
                if(handshakeDone){
                    System.out.println("The handshake was already done before, so lets start receiving !");

                    List<HighwayGridViewAppItem> listOfReceivedFiles=new ArrayList<HighwayGridViewAppItem>();

                    System.out.println("ServerComm receive thread - i am going to try to receive the filesize and name ! ");

                    String fileSizeAsString=(String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Received this initial message with the size: " + fileSizeAsString);
                    String[] valor=fileSizeAsString.split(":");
                    String receivedApkName=valor[0]; //duplicated line pq acho que o nome da app n devia sofrer trim, nao vale a pena.
                    long fileSize=Long.parseLong(valor[1].trim());
                    System.out.println(" ServerComm receive thread : FileSize is at : "+fileSize + " o nome da app e  : "+ receivedApkName);
                    File apkReceived = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + ".apk");
                    int i=1;
                    while(apkReceived.exists()){
                        apkReceived=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+receivedApkName + "("+i+")"+".apk");
                        i++;
                    }
                    i=1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte [8192];
                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(apkReceived);
                    int count=0;
                    int total=0;//so apra ir vendo quanto recebi.
                    while(total<=fileSize && (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                        fos.write(buffer,0,count);
                        total+=count;
                        System.out.println("Server Comm receive thread - already received this ammount : "+total);
                        if(total==fileSize){
                            System.out.println("Reached the end of the file  !");
                            total++;
                            System.out.println("Receive Thread ServerComm o canonical Path que ta e  : " + apkReceived.getCanonicalPath());
                            HighwayGridViewAppItem aux=new HighwayGridViewAppItem(null, receivedApkName, apkReceived.getCanonicalPath());
                            listOfReceivedFiles.add(aux);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("Already received everything ! ");
                    listOfApps=listOfReceivedFiles;
                    System.out.println("ServerComm : O size da lista de apps que recebi e que agora mudei para que possa reenviar pos outros ta a : "+listOfApps.size());
                    String clientName=clientHandler.getNickname();
                    SendThread sendThread = new 
                    new Thread(sendThread){
                    }.start();

                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The **stack ** is :

```
08-26 10:38:40.082 4704-5771/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err: java.io.StreamCorruptedException
08-26 10:38:40.082 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: e
08-26 10:38:40.110 4704-5771/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2109)
08-26 10:38:40.110 4704-5771/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
08-26 10:38:40.110 4704-5771/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at cm.aptoide.lite.HighwayServerComm$ClientHandler.run(HighwayServerComm.java:203)
08-26 10:38:40.110 4704-5771/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at cm.aptoide.lite.HighwayServerComm$ConnectionHandler.run(HighwayServerComm.java:165)
08-26 10:38:40.110 4704-5771/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-26 10:38:40.111 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.corruptStream(ObjectInputStream.java:701)
08-26 10:38:40.111 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:814)
08-26 10:38:40.111 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
08-26 10:38:40.111 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
08-26 10:38:40.111 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at cm.aptoide.lite.HighwayServerComm$ReceiveThread.run(HighwayServerComm.java:395)
08-26 10:38:40.111 4704-6297/cm.aptoide.lite.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The line 395 is :

```
String fileSizeAsString=(String)in.readObject();
```

which is where I try to read the appName and the fileSize (String).

If you guys want i can post the clientSide too, but i know that it is working fine, it sends the file.
Also i dont know why in the stack it is also pointing to the run method of the clientHandler thread, it shouldn't. Before the clientHandler there is also another thread that accepts the client socket and then launches the clientHandler giving the socket as parameter.

Here is my client Code :

I have a connection handler nested class, just to deal with the creation of the stream objects and the socket.

```
    public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket (serverIP,porto);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            in= new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("client comm receive thread - doing the Initial handshake");
            System.out.println("CLientComm connection handler : sending my initial message hello  - my nickname is : "+nickname);
            out.writeObject("Nickname:-:"+nickname);
            System.out.println("ClientComm : Just sent my initial message.");

            try {
                String message = (String) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("ClientComm :_ jist read : " + message   );
                System.out.println("Client Comm receive thread - receive the handshake message from the server. Handshake is done.");
                handshakeDone=true;


                ReceiveThread receiveThread = new ReceiveThread();
                new Thread(receiveThread).start();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here i start the receive thread, that will be waiting to receive a message, but in the layout i have a send button, that will send a choosen apk (it will run this service again with the ACTION = "SEND" and then onStartCommand if the action is send then run the thread SendThread.

Here is the code for that sendTread :

```
     public class SendThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //percorrer a lista de apps a enviar
            File apkToSend;
            long apkToSendSize;

            for(int i=0;i<listOfApps.size();i++){
                HighwayGridViewAppItem tmp=listOfApps.get(i);
                filePath=tmp.getFilePath();
                appName=tmp.getAppName();

                apkToSend=new File(filePath);

                if(apkToSend.exists()){

                    apkToSendSize=apkToSend.length();
                    String apkSize=Long.toString(apkToSendSize);
                    System.out.println(appName +": " +apkSize);
                    out.writeObject(""+appName +": "+ apkSize);//appName to send to have the name of the file
                    System.out.println("ClientComm send thread : going to send this "+appName+": "+apkSize);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte [8192];
                    BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(apkToSend));
                    int count;
                    int total=0; // so para testes - para saber quanto enviei.
                    while((count=bis.read(buffer))!=-1){
                        System.out.println("buffer values :  " + buffer[0]);
                        out.write(buffer,0,count);
                        total+=count;
                        out.reset();
                        System.out.println("Client Comm send thread - already sent this ammount : "+total);
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    bis.close();

                    try {
                        System.out.println("Just sent the app  : "+appName);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);//just to separate each file, to make sure there are no problems with the other side receiving and this one sending
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("There was a problem with the file, the path was incorrect, probably.");
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The message that is suposed be read on the receiver side (where it is giving the error) is the

```
    out.writeObject(""+appName +": "+ apkSize);//appName to send to have the name of the file
```

Notice that before, on the threads to handle the connection (clientHandler and ConnectionHandler) i am successfully sending and trading the data that i want. The problems only show up on the threads down there.

Comment: The stack trace isn't incorrect. It is your expectations that are. You will certainly need to post the missing client code.

Comment: Already added the code from the client side. I really need help for this, i have been searching and trying to solve it for days.

Comment: I found something interesting out, don't know if it is the problem... Maybe anyone reading this might know... I noticed that the messages that are "traded" inside the connection handler thread or in the clientHandler thread (where the inputStreams and outputstreams are local) work fine, but the 1st one that i try , where i have to use a stream that i had to get through a get method (because it was on the other side), doesn't work. Could that be the cause of the problem? If so how could i solve it?